# Correct way for communicating aggregates in DDD

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I have 2 application services which related to 2 different aggregates.

I have some operations where I need to call another service for getting the data and run some actions. I do not want to do that because of transaction boundaries of different aggregates.

What can be the solutions instead of direct communication between services? Technically, it's monolithic spring application.

Answer (score 4):

`Domain Events` could be your answer. From the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation)

> Use domain events to explicitly implement side effects of changes within your domain. In other words, and using DDD terminology, use domain events to explicitly implement side effects across multiple aggregates. Optionally, for better scalability and less impact in database locks, use eventual consistency between aggregates within the same domain.

For example: Consider two aggregates `Customer` and `Order`. When a `Customer` adds an item to the Cart you need to update the `Order`.

Let us assume the name of operation/ method on the `Customer` Domain is `AddItemToCart`. When the operation is complete, then you raise a domain event like `ItemAdded` from the `Customer` aggregate. This event is then handled by a Domain Event Handler. Within the `EventHandler` you would then perform the operation to update the `Order` aggregate.

Note that, Domain Events are different from Integration Events. Handling Domain Events is an application concern. Domain Events could be implemented in memory and within a single transaction. 
Integration Events, on the other hand, propagate the committed transactions to an external application or a different microservice (like Audit service).